# What does collect2.exe do?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, ld

When I examine the code generated by gcc -v -o proggy.exe proggy.o I find that the command line expands into a large bunch of library options and libraries, all of which are linked using collect2.exe.  What happened to ld.exe?  Why don't I see that?  Can someone explain to me what collect2.exe does?

Answer (score 13):

`collect2` is a utility used to generate a table of constructors that `__main` (an auto-generated function called at the beginning of `main`) depends on. Normally you don't see it because it's named `ld` on the file system, and it in turn calls the real ld (typically called `real-ld`, although collect2 will check a number of places looking for it)

Comment: Mr. Mrozek,  

Thanks for your reply.  Next question:  If I use LD.EXE on the command line, what happens to the code?  Suppose I have ld.exe -L/some_lib proggy.o -lsome_lib_lib.  How does this get expanded?

Your previous answer to my initial question was very enlightening!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Worth noting that modern ELF systems won't need that collection (which of course is a nasty hack). They use the ctors and dtors sections of ELF for con- and destructors.

Answer (score 5):

GCC uses a utility called collect2 on nearly all systems to arrange to call various initialization functions at start time. [[link]](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html)