# Dev c++ source file not compiled

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I developed C++ application by Dev C++ with getter and setter and constructors.  I'm sending day,hour,minitue,second variables via constructor and wanna print them.

But gives me error when I run and compile such as "Source file not compiled".

How can I fix this problem?  I've already deleted collect2.exe file but problem still goes on.

**Sinif.CPP**

```
#include "Sinif.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

Sinif::Sinif(int d,int h, int m, int s) {
   day=d;
   hour = h;
   minute = m;
   second = s;

}
int Sinif::getDay() const {
   return day;
}
 void Sinif::setDay(int d) {
   day = d;
}
int Sinif::getHour() const {
   return hour;
}
 void Sinif::setHour(int h) {
   hour = h;
}
 int Sinif::getMinute() const {
   return minute;
}
 void Sinif::setMinute(int m) {
   minute = m;
}
int Sinif::getSecond() const {
   return second;
}
 void Sinif::setSecond(int s) {
   second = s;
}
 void Time::setTime(int d,int h, int m, int s) {
   day=d;
   hour = h;
   minute = m;
   second = s;
}
 void Time::print() const {
   cout << setfill('0');   
   cout << setw(2) << day 
   cout <<":"<< setw(2) << hour  
        << ":" << setw(2) << minute
        << ":" << setw(2) << second << endl;
}
```

**Sinif.h**

```
#ifndef TIME_H 
#define TIME_H   
class Sinif {
private:  
   int day;
   int hour;     
   int minute;   
   int second;  
public: 

   Sinif(int d=0,int h = 0, int m = 0, int s = 0); 
   int getDay() const;   // public getter for private data member hour
   void setDay(int d);
   int getHour() const;   // public getter for private data member hour
   void setHour(int h);   // public setter for private data member hour
   int getMinute() const; // public getter for private data member minute
   void setMinute(int m); // public setter for private data member minute
   int getSecond() const; // public getter for private data member second
   void setSecond(int s); // public setter for private data member second
   void setTime(int d,int h, int m, int s);   // set hour, minute and second
   void print() const; // Print a description of this instance in "hh:mm:ss"
};  // need to terminate the class declaration with a semicolon

#endif  // end of "#ifndef" block
```

**Main CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sinif.h" 
using namespace std;
int main() {
   Sinif t1(25,23, 59, 59);   // Test constructor
   // Test all public member functions
   t1.print(); 
   t1.setDay(17);
   t1.setHour(12);
   t1.setMinute(30);
   t1.setSecond(15);
   t1.print();       // 12:30:15
   cout << "Day is "    << t1.getDay()    << endl;
   cout << "Hour is "   << t1.getHour()   << endl;
   cout << "Minute is " << t1.getMinute() << endl;
   cout << "Second is " << t1.getSecond() << endl;

   Sinif t2;     // Test constructor with default values for hour, minute and second
   t2.print();  // 00:00:00
   t2.setTime(10,1, 2, 3);
   t2.print();  // 01:02:03

   Sinif t3(12); // Use default values for minute and second
   t3.print();  // 12:00:00

}
```

Comment: Unless your program is called "collect2.exe", that program is a very important part of the toolchain and you should definitely not remove it.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Mark 1 eyeball says `Time::setTime` should probably be `Sinif::setTime`.

Comment: `cout << setw(2) << day` is missing a ;

Comment: Why did you delete part of GCC?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822617/what-does-collect2-exe-do

Comment: *I've already deleted collect2.exe file but problem still goes on.* -- If you were working at a job and did this, the problem you would have is that you would no longer have a job.  You just corrupted your installation of the compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not sure that's necessarily a sackable offence up-front, but it doesn't look good

Answer (score 2):

#### What you should do

Read the full build output, which will tell you what is wrong and where.

In this case, that's likely due to things like this:

```
void Time::setTime(int d,int h, int m, int s) {
   day=d;
   hour = h;
   minute = m;
   second = s;
}
```

*(Your class is called `Sinif`, not `Time`.)*

…and this:

```
cout << setw(2) << day
```

*(No terminating semi-colon.)*

With those issues fixed, [your program compiles and runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0431a13a9d166c26) (with what looks like the expected output).

---

#### What you should not do

Delete part of GCC, like `collect2.exe`. You're probably going to have to reinstall your toolchain now.