# No such file or directorycollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, ld, dev-c++

I am getting this error; I tried to resolve it but I was not able to. To check the issue, I have first tried it in VS-CODE then on DEV-CPP but both show the same error which is basically not regarding my program. But I am getting that:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Running";
    return 0;
}
```

That's the error:

> cannot open output file newFile.exe: No such file or directorycollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

All of my old programs which were running showing the same issue.

Comment: ***No such file or directorycollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status*** looks like you somehow deleted part of your mingw install or perhaps your AV deleted it. collect2.exe is part of the build process. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822617/what-does-collect2-exe-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822617/what-does-collect2-exe-do)

Comment: Actually, I haven't deleted anything instead I was doing some questions first view runs correctly but after that, this error occurs. I had reinstalled it but that doesn't change anything. I tried to run my Java programs but they were also not running as they were running earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I have resolved this problem by resetting my PC. If there is another way, please tell me. I had done so because None of my program was running neither Java nor CPP.

Comment: this worked for me as well on windows 11

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem. This is how I resolved it
Go to controlled folder access in ransomware protection in widows defender and allow the folder in which you are saving the cpp file to make changes. When you go to blocked history, you will see Protected folder access blocked, just allow it if you see the folder in which you are saving the cpp files for vs code.